# What's wrong with my newly installed PyGame? Details in description

Tags: python, windows, pygame

My Python version is 2.7 and whenever I try doing import pygame it shows the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module> 
import pygame 
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pygame\__init__.py", line 95, in <module> 
from pygame.base import * 
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Looks like it's some sorta' dll load failure but I just can't figure out what's wrong. Please help, thx

Comment: Are you using the 32 or 64 bit version of Python?

Comment: Re-installed both pygame and python in 32-bit solved my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have had a similar problem before. What you have to do is download the 32-bit version of python, and make sure all python related downloads are 32-bit.